# Save date into database with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date

I'm still new in Laravel. Currently, I'm learning and working on Carbon. I already looking on every documentation and other solution but I still don't get it. I hope there is someone can teach and show me step by step how to correct or improve my code.

**ComplaintController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (count($request->defect_id) > 0) {
            foreach($request->defect_id as $item=>$v) {
                 $data = array(
                     'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],
                     'image' => $filename,
                     'description' => $request->description[$item],
                     'report_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                     'created_at' => Carbon::today()->toDateString(),
                     'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
                 );
                Complaint::insert($data);
```

I'm saving `created_at` field as date only, no time and it is in the format of `(yy-mm-dd)`.

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Defect Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Report Date</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($complaint as $c)
           <tr>
              <td>{{$c->defect->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$c->description}}</td>
              <td><img src="{{ Storage::url('complaint/' . $c->image)}}" class="" alt="{{$c->image}}"></td>
              <td>{{$c->created_at->toDateString()}}</td>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
        @endforeach
   </table>
</div>
```

My date is still showing finely in the table as `(yy-mm-dd)` but I want the date to be in format of `(dd/mm/yy)` so I try to use this kind of code `{{$c->created_at->toDateString()->format("dd/mm/yy")}}` and there is error appeared which is `Call to a member function format() on string`. Later on, I need to add another field for duedate and use this function `addDays(30)`. So, what I need to do? I'm guessing that I need to put another function in my model but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I am giving an alternative use `PHP date()` function like this `date("d/m/Y")`.

Comment: You simply don't use `->toDateString()` as that converts it to a String. `$c->created_at->format('dd/mm/yy')` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tim Lewis as well,
replace

```
{{ $c->created_at->toDateString()->format("dd/mm/yy") }}
```

to

```
{{ $c->created_at->format("dd/mm/yy") }}
```

As `toDateString()` converts it to string before changing the format.

---

You can also try using standard php format for datetime, instead of **Carbon** class,

```
{{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($c->created_at)) }}
```

---

As for your second question of you want to add new table data column ,

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ $c->defect->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $c->description }}</td>
  <td><img src="{{ Storage::url('complaint/' . $c->image)}}" class="" alt="{{$c->image}}"></td>
  <td>{{ $c->created_at->format("dd/mm/yy") }}</td>
  <td>{{ $c->created_at->addDays(30)  }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You answer all my question perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

To save the date in the format dd/mm/yy, I would use the following:

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now()))
```

To reformat the date in a view, I would use:

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($c->created_at))
```

I prefer to use the base php functions wherever possible to keep things simple.

If someone knows a reason not to, please let me know.

As for the adding of days,

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($c->created_at) + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30))
```

Should work.

Most date related problems can be solved with strtotime(), its very useful. Be sure to read up on it here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: *"If someone knows a reason not to, please let me know."* - There's no reason not to use `date()` over `Carbon` functions, except that the question specifically asks for a solution "with Carbon". Also, Carbon is built in to Laravel, so there's no reason _not_ to use it :)

Comment: you need to read the question @Irdina Zulkeflee wants format dd/mm/yy, why so much hurry ?

Answer (score 0):

**Casted date fields:**

In Laravel the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are casted as date fields already. So you don't have to transform this into date formats.

You can simply do

```
<td>{{ $c->created_at->format("d/m/y") }}</td>
```

Fields `created_at` and `updated_at` are also automatically filled
So you don't need to fill this fields

You can simply do

```
$data = array(
    'defect_id' => $request->defect_id[$item],
    'image' => $filename,
    'description' => $request->description[$item],
    'report_by' => Auth::user()->id,
);
Complaint::create($data);
```

**Extra date field `duedate`**
When you add custom date fields you need to cast them in the model to be date.

Add this in you model:

```
protected $dates = ['duedate'];
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, `Model::insert()` doesn't automatically set `created_at` and `updated_at`, which is why they were present in the array. `Model::create()` does though :)

Comment: @TimLewis yes, I think you are right! So let's use ::create() then ;-)